# Delphi TComboBox with fulltext search and bitmap (owner draw)

Tags: delphi, bitmap, vcl, ownerdrawn

I use this code: [How to make a combo box with fulltext search autocomplete support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466547/how-to-make-a-combo-box-with-fulltext-search-autocomplete-support) to create custom TComboBox control with searching.

Everything was working fine but I decided to add bitmaps (pictures) into it using this method: [ComboBox Simple with Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283783/combobox-simple-with-bitmap)

But when I added the second code I lost the searching functionality. To enable Owner drawing I added **csOwnerDrawFixed** style to control in constructor

```
constructor TComboBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  ...
  Style := csOwnerDrawFixed; ; << Added to enable owner draw
end;
```

How can I combine these two codes? The strange thing is when I run the project I can see the control redrawing correctly first time but then all data are lost and no drawing is done.

Comment: I am pretty sure you better forget about doing this with TComboBox and make your own control from scratch.

Comment: You are asking a bit much for others to inspect two separate bits of code and then guess how you merged them together.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rohit Gupta: Actually it is pretty easy to merge that 2 codes: simply place 2nd code into 1st one and rename class :)

I did this but the code is not working - painting the control causes freezing of software and I could not solve this issue that is why I asked for help.

@Warren P: you are right, the better is to create custom control which handles everything.

I created my own control which is basically **TEdit** with owner draw and **TListBox** with owner draw and **TSpeedButton** which works fine:

[image: Custom control with drawing]

I need to do some tweaking now and finished control will be available on my blog.

If someone is interested then grab it later on http://unsigned.sk/blog/ (I will post comment here once finished).

Thanks to all for ideas!

Comment: I just released full sources for this component: https://delphicomponents.codeplex.com/

Comment: And here is blog with some details: http://www.unsigned.sk/blog/index.php?itemid=89#more